# Change logo depending on domain

Tags: domain, logo

I have a question which i can't sort out.

I'm having 1 WordPress installation on one main domain. But now I have many more domains refering to the main domain. What I want now is the following:

- When people go to the main domain "www.a.com" the logo "a.com" needs to show.
- When people go the another domain for example "www.b.com" which refers to "www.a.com" the logo "b.com" needs to show.

I can't figure out how to do this.

Maybe you guys can help me with this?

Comment: Are these separate WordPress installs on the different domains?  You'd need to specify a different `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` settings for each site, either in the `wp_options` table, or in the `wp-config` file.

Do the sites have different content, or are they identical except for the logo?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps get the http referrer on the home page and store it in a cookie, then read the cookie on each page load and show the corresponding logo.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the original referrer of the page and store it in a session variable to make sure you keep the alternative logo even as the user is clicking through the site. So, you could do something like this:

```
session_start();

if ( !isset( $_SESSION["referURL"] ) )
  $_SESSION["referURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

$ref = $_SESSION["referURL"];
if (strpos($ref, 'a.com') !== false) {$logo='path_to_image_a'}
elseif (strpos($ref, 'b.com') !== false) {$logo='path_to_image_b'}
... do something with $logo ...
```

PS: If you are using the theme logo built into WP, you can use the [`get_custom_logo`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_custom_logo/) filter to change the logo, so you can put the above code in that filter.